# How to fix gcloud app deployment error Cloud build failed. Failure status: UNKNOWN?

Tags: node.js, deployment, gcloud

I am trying deploy my node.js project into Google Cloud.  It works fine on localhost but when I try to deploy into GCP I am getting an error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Cloud build failed. Failure status:
>   UNKNOWN: Error Response: [2] Build failed .

[image]

Comment: The line before the last of the error message tells you to check the build logs for more details. Please, take a look and if you can't figure it out, paste the relevant part of the log file here.

Comment: i coudn't figure out from the log file. Here is complete log file.

Comment: starting build "74fce248-f0a2-4408-89ad-f4408d4068ed"

FETCHSOURCE
Fetching storage object: gs://staging.whatmate-nodejs.appspot.com/us.gcr.io/whatmate-nodejs/appengine/default.20181111t153759:latest#1541931249630575
Copying gs://staging.whatmate-nodejs.appspot.com/us.gcr.io/whatmate-nodejs/appengine/default.20181111t153759:latest#1541931249630575...
/ [1 files][  1.4 MiB/  1.4 MiB]
Operation completed over 1 objects/1.4 MiB.
BUILD

Comment: Starting Step #0
Step #0: Pulling image: gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/nodejs/gen-dockerfile@sha256:98d9069aa67a763de7e6fd81c41f937b171917f1e83a1afce30fc3d618a3c110
Step #0: Digest: sha256:98d9069aa67a763de7e6fd81c41f937b171917f1e83a1afce30fc3d618a3c110
Step #0: Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/nodejs/gen-dockerfile@sha256:98d9069aa67a763de7e6fd81c41f937b171917f1e83a1afce30fc3d618a3c110
Step #0: Checking for Node.js.
Step #0: WARNING:  Your package.json does not specify a supported Node.js version.  Please pin your application to a major version of the Node.js runtime.

Comment: Next time paste the log file into your original question. And format it with code (CTRL+K)

Comment: Finished Step #0
Starting Step #1
Step #1: Pulling image: gcr.io/cloud_builders/docker@sha256:db129145c89be18778616f6468eff312286914b2060e918d7b3cb2e6733a7bc8
Step #1: sha256:db129145c89be18778616f6468eff312286914b2060e918d7b3cb2e6733a7bc8: Pulling from cloud_builders/docker
Step #1: e5c573070776: Already exists
Step #1: a7e8e7eaedca: Already exists
Step #1: 3c2cba919283: Already exists
Step #1: 272ea2083378: Pulling fs layer
Step #1: 272ea2083378: Verifying Checksum
Step #1: 272ea2083378: Download complete
Step #1: 272ea2083378: Pull complete

Comment: Still there is a lot in .Please share you mail id. I will send in a attachment.

Comment: `WARNING: Your package.json does not specify a supported Node.js version. Please pin your application to a major version of the Node.js runtime.`  here is your error. Paste your package.json into the end of your `question` Not into the comments.

Comment: But I have deployed plenty of times the same thing without specifying version. This project i tried to deploy again is from last deployed backup. And gcloud app engine says it allocates the project to latest version of node js if not specified. (Is their any limit for no. of deployments of the project ?)

Comment: Please, paste your log file and package.json into the end of `your original question` (just edit it) and `format them` (with CTRL+K) . I can't help you until you provide the relevant informations.

Comment: I couldn't edit the question. 
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1xp7_hix68ajRQy4qIL1qtJp6jNpNqw9rrBf1k6Ei3Dg/edit?usp=sharing

i have added the log file and package.json in google docs please check here.Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your build fails because it can not build `bcrypt`. Solution could be to remove it from the package json. Which you can do, because you already use `bcrypt-nodejs` which does the same thing and it is pure js, so it does not require to install native add-ons.

Comment: yes.Thanks a lot. Now deployment was successfull. But i want to know what was the problem with bcrypt module. 2 days back i had deployed the same package.json.

Comment: No worries. Please don't forget to accept the answer. see [this](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/issues/432) issue for details.